# Using jQuery find string A or B and replace based on css class and ID

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, how do you check for and replace the occurrence of stringA or stringB when it falls under a specific css class and ID?

```
stringA = " | "
stringB = "|" 
css     = .login #bav

<div class="login">
    <p id="nav">
        <a href="#">oh ya</a> |
        <a href="#" title="Password Lost and Found"></a>
    </p>
</div>
```

I have variations of this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".login #nav").replaceText( /testA|testB/gi, "fooBar" );
  });
});
```

Comment: You want to replace the `|` character (with or without spaces) in the text of the `#nav` element?

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` you don't pass jQuery in `});
});` to your anon function so that will not be accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With what I understand of your problem, I'd suggest:

```
$('#nav').contents().each(function(){
    if (this.nodeType === 3) {
        var str = this.nodeValue;
        this.nodeValue = str.replace(/(\|)|(\s+\|\s+)/g,'foobar');
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Fjx7N/1/).

References:

- jQuery:

  - [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/).
  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- 'Plain' JavaScript:

  - [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
  - [`Node.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType).
  - [`Node.nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeValue).

Comment: Thanks for the references, that helps when your learning...also I forgot to wrap the <p> tag in a <div class="login">. How do you add the class login along with $nac?

Comment: In exactly the same way you would with CSS (the beauty of jQuery is that, for the most part, its selectors *are* CSS-selectors): `$('.login #nav')`

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var stringA = " | ";
    var stringB = "|";
    var nav = $("#nav");
    nav.html(nav.html().replace(stringA, "fooBar").replace(stringB, "fooBar"));
});
```

Comment: I need it to find " | " and "|" not as an assigned varable but it it falls under .login #nav.